# Changing jQuery Event from click to on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following  onclick function  that triggers the object to become full screen when clicked. I want the object to be fullscreen when the page loads without having to click.

```
  fbNav.find('ul li.fullscreen').on('click', function(e){
        if(!fullscreen) {
            fbFullscreen.show();
            fbFullscreen.append(fbCont);

            $window.trigger('resize');
        } else {
            fbParent.append(fbCont);
            fbFullscreen.hide();

            $window.trigger('resize');
        }

        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
    });
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You better put the main logic in a function and call the same function on ready and click.

```
function fullscreen(){
    if(!fullscreen) {
        fbFullscreen.show();
        fbFullscreen.append(fbCont);

        $window.trigger('resize');
    } else {
        fbParent.append(fbCont);
        fbFullscreen.hide();

        $window.trigger('resize');
    }

    fullscreen = !fullscreen;
}

//will be executed when page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
    fullscreen();
});

//will be executed on click
fbNav.find('ul li.fullscreen').on('click', function(e){
    fullscreen();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger click event on page load.

`fbNav.find('ul li.fullscreen').trigger("click");`